# Defining strong limit cardinals in $ZF$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I do not understand the following passage/footnote in the book I am currently reading:

> An initial ordinal $\lambda$ is called a *strong limit cardinal* if
>   $2^\kappa < \lambda$ for every $\kappa < \lambda$. Note that this
>   definition makes sense even in $ZF$.

Then, footnote:

> If $\lambda$ is a strong limit cardinal, then $\mathcal P (\kappa) $
>   can be wellordered for every $\kappa < \lambda$. Thus, in $ZF$ alone
>   one cannot prove the existence of an uncountable strong limit
>   cardinal. But it is also relatively consistent with $ZF$ that an
>   uncountable strong limit cardinal exists while the full Axiom of
>   Choice fails.

---

What I understand: $\lambda$ is a cardinal, hence in particular an ordinal and hence well-ordered. If $2^\kappa < \lambda$ we therefore get a well-order on $\mathcal P (\kappa)$ induced by an order-isomorphism between $\mathcal P (\kappa)$ and some ordinal $\alpha < \lambda$.

What I don't understand: The sentence starting with "Thus...". How does it follow from $\mathcal P (\kappa)$ being well-ordered that in $ZF$ one cannot prove the existence of an uncountable strong limit cardinal? And: Would you show me how to prove the existence of an uncountable strong limit cardinal?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You need choice to say that every cardinal is an ordinal. If every cardinal is an ordinal then every set $x$ can be well-ordered by the order induced by the bijection $x \to |x|$.

Comment: ${\aleph_0}$ is a strong limit cardinal because For any cardinal less than it (which will be finite), you can never reach infinity by repeating the powerset operation infinitely many times. Any result will be finite. i.e. is S is a set with 2 elements, then P(S) = 4, P(P(S)) = 16. This gives cardinalities 2, 4, 16, 65536, etc. All of these can get arbitrarily large, but will never "exceed" infinity, if this makes any sense.

Comment: However, if we apply the repeated powerset operation on ${\aleph_0}$ infinite times, there is no clear limit (Cantor's Paradox). As with the finite set (see above comment), the limit is clearly ${\aleph_0}$. It is unclear whether or not the Cardinality of the Continuum is a strong limit cardinal.

Answer (score 5):

The existence of a strong limit would prove the existence of a well-order of the reals, because it has to be greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$ and the first passage would apply.  Since we know $ZF$ doesn't prove such a well-order exists, there cannot be a proof that a strong limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

It is consistent that the axiom of choice fails and $2^\omega$ cannot be well-ordered. It follows that no power set of an ordinal can be well-ordered, and so no limit cardinals are strong limit cardinals.

An interesting paper on the topic is:

> Blass A., Dimitriou I. M. , and Löwe B. **Inaccessible cardinals without the axiom of choice.** *Fundamenta Mathematicae* , vol.**194**, pp. 179-189

Which can be found [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/dimitri/PP-2006-46.text.pdf).

---

In ZFC to show that there is an uncountable strong limit cardinal, remember the definition of $\beth$ numbers and consider $\beth_\delta$ for any limit ordinal $\delta$.

As for the last remark about consistency, we can force that the axiom of choice fails *above* the first strong limit cardinal, $\kappa=\beth_\omega$. In this case all the cardinals up to $\beth_\omega$ and their power sets can be well-ordered and so $\kappa$ is still a strong limit cardinal but the axiom of choice fails in general.